# Symfony Form Collections with ODM and ORM

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

A Task `Entity` requires the ability to set a Tag `Document`.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Task
{
    protected $description;

    protected $tagId;

    public function getDescription()
    public function setDescription($description)

    //Mongo id
    public function setTagId($tagId)
    {
        $this->tagId = $tagId;
        return $this;
    }

    //Mongo id
    public function getTagId()
    {
        return $this->tagId;
    }

}
```

Based on the example from https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html which uses only ORM for both Task and Tag, how can Tag be stored in MongoODM instead?

A Transformer could convert a user input to a TagDocument and call `Task->setId($tag->getId())`.  However if the Document does not exist, when should it be created?

Creating a Document inside a Transformer would work but persisting would seem to break the single responsibility principle.

Likewise `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` could be used but a `Form` should not be responsible for Persisting either.

How should a `TagDocument` be added to a `TaskEntity`?

The `TagDocument` and `TaskEntity` should both be persisted in the same Request. i.e. I would prefer not to create a separate ajax request to first create a `TagDocument` and return the `id`, this could result in many created but never used `TagDocuments`.

Comment: If you create the Tag as an Entity, and you declare it as a relation / reference, I don't think you have to worry about persisting one before the other. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/bidirectional-references.html#one-to-many

Comment: The data stores can not be changed, Tag must remain managed by ODM and Task by ORM.  It's not an option in this case, the form collection example is only being used to simplify the problem.  The `TagDocument` will have to be persisted before the `TaskEntity` in order for `Task.TagId` to be set, but just as long as it's done in a single request that is ok.